# Alarm Receiver Service not working

Tags: java, android, service, alarmmanager, alarm

Here is my Main Activity where the Alarm Receiver service is called

```
Context context=getApplicationContext();
    alarmMgr = (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, MyBroadcastReceiver.class);
    alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);
    alarmMgr.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),
            1000 * 60, alarmIntent);
```

Here is my MyBroadcastReceiver class

```
public class MyBroadcastReceiver  extends BroadcastReceiver {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    String LOG_TAG="DevicePolicyAdmin";
    Log.v(LOG_TAG, "Service Started");
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    int hour=c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
    int  minute=c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
    Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar(1990, 1, 1, hour, minute);
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm");
    String date = sdf.format(calendar.getTime());
    String str=date.charAt(0)+""+date.charAt(1)+""+date.charAt(3)+""+date.charAt(4);
    MainActivity.minochaDevicePolicyManager.resetPassword(str, 0);
}
}
```

What is the issue here? in the logcat the LOG "Enabling Policies" isnt coming. that means the Service hasnt been called. Whats wrong with this code?

Comment: how is `calendar` initialised in the main activity?

Comment: The same way as over here